# scheme constructors and accessors

Tags: constructor, scheme, accessor

**USING SCHEME:**

I am working on a question in my assignment that asks the follows:

> **A toy data structure specifies the name of a toy, a description, the acquisition price, and the recommended sales price. Create
>   constructors and accessors for the toy structure, ensuring that you do
>   not use Racket’s builtin structs [1 marks]. Using only your accessors
>   to get at the data in your structure, define a function that sorts a
>   list of toy structures by the difference between the two prices [2
>   marks].**

Is the question asking to create my own toy data structure with constructors that has the name of the toy,description, and acquisition price and accessors to get the variables of toy like name or description?

if so, how do i do this?

is there a keyword like struct in scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the question asking to create my own toy data structure with constructors that has the name of the toy,description, and acquisition price and accessors to get the variables of toy like name or description? if so, how do i do this?

Yes, that's exactly what the assignment says. Hint: a simple list will do, store each field in a position and the accessors will return the element at the position. For instance, if we store the name in the first position, then the accessor will return the `car` of the list, and so on.

> Is there a keyword like struct in scheme?

Yes, oddly enough in Racket is called [`struct`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html) (it's a macro, not a keyword). Also in R7RS (or in SRFI-9) we have record types. But the assignment specifically states that you must not use this!

Comment: so how do i answer this question?

Comment: @user3259073 I told you above! create a list with the values for each field, and access each one according to their positions. For example, if the list contains the name, description and price then the accessors for each one will return the first, second and third element of the list. Create a new list for each toy. As easy as pie.

Comment: ohh ok, sorry I didnt read the first part of your original answer. So your saying, something like:

creating a toy with a list of the name description and price (define toy (list("ted" "teddybear" 10)))

(define (name x) (car x)) - access the name of x 
... and so on for the other parts of the list?

Comment: @user3259073 that's the idea yes, but don't hard-code the values in the list, pass them along as parameter for the function, so you can call the same constructor to create different toys, simply by changing what parameters get passed along

Comment: I think I see what your saying, so like creating a generic toy:

**(define (toy a b c)(list a b c))** >> which would create a list given a b c

ie. (toy "ted" "teddy" 10)
> '("ted" "teddy" 10)

Comment: @user3259073 that's right, you got it! now go ahead and ace that homework ;)

Comment: Ok ok,stay with me for a minute,im still working out a few bugs xD so far i have:

`(define (toy a b c)
  (list(a b c)))

(define (access-name x) (car x))
(define (access-desc x)(cadr x))
(define (access-price x)(caddr x))
`

where each access definition accesses a different part of "x" 

but when I create a toy using toy I get back:

`> (toy "ted" "teddy" 10)
. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: "ted"
  arguments...:
   "teddy"
   10
> toy "ted" "teddy" 10
#<procedure:toy>
"ted"
"teddy"
10`

Comment: Almost right. To create a list, do this: `(list a b c)`. And that's it.

Comment: OK but then how do I use the access modifiers? Like after I've created my toy,'("ted" "teddy" 10) if I wanted to access the name, when I try (access-name toy),it doesnt work because im trying to access a procedure. how do access the toy i just created?

Comment: The procedure is used for creating a new toy, that you can save for later use: `(define toy1 (toy "car" "a car" 10))`. Then you call the accessors on the toy: `(access-name toy1)`

Comment: Technically isnt that still hard coding toy1,toy2,...etc.? just using another definition to create the toy information in a certain format and then use the accessors?

Comment: We're _naming_ an object we just created, it's values are not hard-coded, but of course the _variable_ name is, if the variable name kept changing, how would we refer to it?

Comment: Ok I follow what your saying now, thank you. Now I just need to create a function that displays the toys by accessing then using my accessors

Comment: @user3259073 ok, but that's on your own, this answer is too long already ;) . One final hint, before I say good-bye: Read about the [`sort`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29) function.

Comment: I think you might be mixing Scheme with Racket. There is no such thing as `struct` in Scheme, but you have `record types` in R7RS and [SRFI-9 Record types](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-9/srfi-9.html) for previous versions.